# 1990 Acura Integra LS manual transmission clutch replacement

Tags: transmission, clutch, manual-transmission, acura, integra

I'm trying to replace the clutch in my manual transmission 1990 Acura Integra LS (5 speed, 4-cylinder). In the course of doing this, I need to remove the transmission which is connected to the shift arm and I can't see how to disconnect the shift arm from the transmission. It looks to be pinned together, but I'm concerned about trying to simply beat the pins out. There are no visible bolt heads that I've been able to find. I don't see how it would be practical to remove the transmission without disconnecting this.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to go from here?

EDIT: found a spring clip and pin under a rubber boot.  Popped those out (with some difficulty) and got it all free.

Comment: Instead of an edit, how about submitting what you actually did as an answer?  That way, you'll leave some breadcrumbs for the next person who has the exact same problem to follow.

Comment: I swear that "Add Answer" button wasn't there yesterday!  *laugh*  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found a spring clip and pin under a rubber boot. Popped those out (with some difficulty) and got it all free.

Comment: Great!  You know what would be awesome?  A picture or a diagram from a shop manual.  Then if I ever went back and bought back my Integra, I'd know what to look for.